# Ubuntu 14.04 - Unknown Display - Resolution limited

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a 2nd monitor (Samsung) but Ubuntu cannot detect the monitor as well as the best resolution (1680*1050). So far the max. resolution is 1360*768. please see the screenshot - display settings

One thing I tried is to use “addmode” but received the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  29
Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I have also tried to update the NVIDA driver but it didn't help.